# How to handle differences between OpenGL implementations

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I just got myself an error that only happened due to not having filled a sampler array, in an AMD GPU, I could only see it in RenderDOC and the debug output didn't alert me of that. How one may know the requirements for different OpenGL implementations in different cards? Do they have some specific documentation that you should follow, all tutorials and books I've read so far basically just consider what is needed for each command in Khronos docs

Comment: There is no such documentation/references,.. I would be aware of. Actually, this things are changing on a constant bases. Any new GPU driver version might change how implementation defined parts are handled. The only way to catch those things is to test on as many different GPUs as possible.

Comment: Undefined bheavior and implementation-defined behavior are called that way because they are well... exactly what the name says. Don't rely on things which the spec does not guarantee.

Comment: So just ignoring those unless they produce some actual side effect in my application would be appropriate? It did run fine even with the error, I don't know if doing more than the required by the spec to support different implementations will do more harm than good

Comment: @Triangles: "more than required by the spec" -- if you used a sampler and didn't initialize it you didn't do the basic of what is required by the spec. Just follow the spec for your OpenGL version: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php

Comment: @Triangles: What "error" did you get? What did you not fill in exactly? Implementations aren't allowed to give out OpenGL errors for implementation-dependent reasons (outside of extensions). It is not clear if what you're talking about is due to user error or something else.

Comment: I'm getting glDrawElements 1282 when I run my app in RenderDoc, what doesn't happen without it, my arrays are in a UBO(in this style `vec4 colors[64]`) and by not filling I mean I'm not sending all 64 vec4's but only some, I thought I had a sampler in there but I forgot I switched to a simpler 2D array. When I remove the pass that uses these uniforms etc the error in RenderDoc is gone, I confused the different debug extensions(khr, amd etc) and thought I wasn't getting the error myself because RenderDoc would be using the amd ext but I think that's not how the debugoutput extension works